# Java Inheritance: Why super class variable is referred

Tags: java

I have a super class "Sam" and a sub-class "SubSam"

```
 public class Sam {

String msg;
String msg1;

Sam(String mm, String mm1) {
    msg = mm;
    msg1 = mm1;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.msg + "  " + this.msg1;
    }
}

class SubSam extends Sam {

String msg1="C";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SubSam obj = new SubSam();
    System.out.println(obj);
}

SubSam() {
    super("A", "B");
}
}
```

The output is:

```
A  B
```

Why "toString()" is referring the instance fields of "Sam" instead of "SubSam". The output should be: A C

I am thinking over it for a long time now, but not getting?

Comment: The problem you are encountering is called "Shadowing" - take a look at this http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-is-variable-hiding-and-shadowing/15

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza : When i am debugging then "this.msg1" is showing "C", but while printing it is printing  "B". Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because instance variables in Java aren't overridden, quite simply. A subclass can define a variable with the same name as one defined in one of its superclasses, but it counts as a separate variable for all intents and purposes.

For example, consider the following code:

```
public class A {
    public String var;
}

public class B extends A {
    public int var;
}
```

Given those definitions, instances of `B` will have two variables, one being of type `String`, the other of type `int`, but both will be named `var`. They are still separate variables which can be independently assigned to and read from, and Java does not consider there being anything wrong with this.

If you want to override behavior as you indicate you want, you need to use methods instead. For instance, you could do it like this:

```
public class A {
    public String msg;
    private String msg1;

    public A(String mm, String mm1) {
        this.msg  = mm;
        this.msg1 = mm1;
    }

    public String msg1() {
        return(this.msg1);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return(this.msg + " " + msg1());
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    public B() {
        super("A", "B");
    }

    @Override
    public String msg1() {
        return("C");
    }
}
```

Now, if you call `System.out.println(new B());`, it will print `A C`.

Comment: When i am debugging then "this.msg1" is showing "C", but while printing it is printing "B". Why?

Comment: Because your `SubSam` instance has, in reality, not one but two variables named `msg1`, one defined by the `Sam` class and the other defined by the `SubSam` class. The code defined in the `Sam` class refers to the variable defined in the `Sam` class, which is assigned the value `"B"`, while the code in the `SubSam` class refers to the variable defined in the `SubSam` class, which is assigned the value `"C"`. Your debugger probably only shows one of them, since it is unusual practice to define variables with the same name.

Comment: but i am printing an object of "SubSam" class, so in "toString()" "this" should refer to "SubSam instance"?

Comment: No, because the `toString` method is defined in the `Sam` class, so it refers the the variable defined therein. `this` does refer to a `SubSam` instance, for sure, but the `toString` code refers to the `msg1` variable defined by the `Sam` class, since that's how that name resolves when the `toString` method is compiled.

Answer (score 1):

You're not overriding toString, so the toString method of the superclass is called. It prints msg and msg1 for the superclass, not for the subclass.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the `msg1` in the sub-class, but in it's contructor you are passing

```
super("A","B");
```

At this point the variable that are being initialized in the `super` i.e. the contructor of main class are the main class' variable that are being used using the `this` keyword in `toString` method.